# Spec output in terminal

Tags: ruby, rspec, rbenv

Whenever I run a test, I see this on the terminal:

```
/home/kinsomicrote/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/ruby -I
/home/kinsomicrote/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib:
/home/kinsomicrote/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-support-3.3.0/lib
/home/kinsomicrote/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/exe/rspec
--pattern spec/\*\*\{,/\*/\*\*\}/\*_spec.rb failed
```

It is usually at the start and the end of the output. Any reason why I am seeing this?

Comment: What version of  `rails` and `rspec` do you use? How do you run the tests? Using `rspec spec` or other way?

Comment: Oh! Thanks! I was using `rake spec`, tried `rspec spec` and it was okay

Comment: Great!! Glad I helped. Next time try showing the full command, or at least show how you are running it so we can help you better. I'll add what I've said as an answer so if you want to, you can mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Answer has been marked as correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running `rspec spec` instead of `rake spec`

Answer (score 1):

I was using `rake spec` to run tests, instead of `rspec spec`. Thanks to @JuanBoca for pointing it out.